# How to pass Id from jQuery to controller?

Tags: visualforce

How to pass Id value to the controller using apex:param

```
$j('ul.slds-lookup__list1 a').click(function(e) {
    $j('#account_name').val($j(this)[0].innerText);
    $j('#account_name').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $j('#account_name_lookup').css("display", "none");
    $j('#accId').val($j(this)[0].id);
    //=========New Logic =============== 
    var AccountId = $j('[id$=accId]').val();
    alert('value check ======>' + AccountId);  //Account Id
});
```

---

```
<!--  Clone Button Logic here ------>
<div class="slds-box">
    <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-1">
        <div class="slds-align--absolute-center">
            <apex:commandButton value="Clone" id="cloneButton" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral"  onclick="dateselect()" >
                <apex:param name="AccountId" value="{!oSQ.Customer__c}" assignTo="{!AccountId}"/>  //How to pass that id to controller
            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:commandButton status="statusId" value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral"/>
            <apex:actionStatus id="statusId" onstart="showLoading();" onstop="hideLoading();">
                <apex:facet name="start">   
                    <apex:image value="/img/loading.gif" />                 
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br></br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function save(){
    paramFunction('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
}  



</script>

    <apex:form >

        <apex:actionFunction name="paramFunction" action="{!ParamFunction}">       
             <apex:param id="paramId1" name="param1" value="" />
             <apex:param id="paramId2" name="param2" value="" />
             <apex:param id="paramId3" name="param3" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>  
    </apex:form>



    public with sharing class ParamExampleController {

    public void ParamFunction() {
        String param1 = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get(param1);
        String param2 = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param2'); 
        String param3 = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param3'); 
        System.debug('======================= ' + param1);
        System.debug('======================= ' + param2);
        System.debug('======================= ' + param3);
    }
}
```